# iPad notes to Pages

Tags: ipad, pages, notes.app, ipados

Using my iPad Pro, I draft many notes using the well-known Notes app. Next, I would like to polish them and add more detail therefore on Pages, but I could not find yet an efficient way to “import” from Notes to Pages, apart from copy/paste, which produces awful results. Anybody knows how to do this?

Comment: Do you have a Mac or iMac computer?

Comment: @jmh , I have a MacBook with Mojave, why do you ask it?

Answer (score 1):

You can save the notes you want as PDF's by using 'Export as PDF' under the file menu while in Notes. There is an app on the App Store called 'PDF to Pages Free'. This free version will convert up to 3 pages from a PDF to a Pages document. Once the file is converted you can edit it further in Pages.